# Redux-forms - Errors prop is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, redux, redux-form

I am using 'redux-forms' in my app and have a validation function passed to the form container component for sync validation. When I input an incorrect value in one of the fields, I get displayed the error message inline (under the field), however, the `error` prop is still `undefined` as passed by the container component to the form react component.

The form code:

```
const LoginFormComponent = props => {
  return (
    <div className="formContainer">
      <form>
        <Field name="email" label="Email" type="text" placeholder="email" component={InputComponent} />
        <Field name="password" label="Password" type="password" placeholder="password" component={InputComponent} />
        <button className="btn" type="submit">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

const LoginForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'loginForm',
  validate: validateLoginForm
})(LoginFormComponent);

export default LoginForm;
```

The updated props sent to the above React component are:

```
anyTouched: true
array: Object { insert: bindActionCreator/<(), move: bindActionCreator/<(), pop: bindActionCreator/<(), … }
asyncValidate: function Form/_this.asyncValidate()
asyncValidating: false
autofill: function bindActionCreator/<()
blur: function bindActionCreator/<()
change: function bindActionCreator/<()
clearAsyncError: function bindActionCreator/<()
clearFields: function bindActionCreator/<()
clearSubmit: function bindActionCreator/<()
clearSubmitErrors: function bindActionCreator/<()
destroy: function bindActionCreator/<()
dirty: true
dispatch: function dispatch()
error: undefined // <===== this is the value I am looking to get
form: "loginForm"
handleSubmit: function Form/_this.submit()
initialValues: undefined
initialize: function bindActionCreator/<()
initialized: false
invalid: true
pristine: false
pure: true
reset: function bindActionCreator/<()
submit: function bindActionCreator/<()
submitFailed: false
submitSucceeded: false
submitting: false
touch: function bindActionCreator/<()
triggerSubmit: undefined
untouch: function bindActionCreator/<()
valid: false
validate: function createValidator/<()
warning: undefined
__proto__: Object { … }
```

Notice the `error` key has a value of `undefined`

As per request, the validation function is:

```
const validateLoginForm = createValidator({
  email: [checkEmail, checkRequired],
  password: [checkRequired]
});

export function createValidator(rules, params) {
  return (data = {}) => {
    const errors = {};
    Object.keys(rules).forEach(key => {
      const rule = join([].concat(rules[key])); // concat enables both functions and arrays of functions
      const error = rule(data[key], data, { key, ...params });
      if (error) {
        errors[key] = error;
      }
    });
    return errors;
  };
}

const join = rules => (value, data, params) => rules.map(rule => rule(value, data, params)).filter(error => !!error)[0];
```

What am I doing wrong. Just to clarify that the validate function is returning an errors object.

Comment: Can you add the code of your validation function?

Comment: how do you implement `InputComponent`? actually the validation errors would be passed to it.

Comment: @AliQanavatian The InputComponent is just a pure functional component.

Comment: @Kayote have you checked the redux's form state? if that's get updated it means that component might need to be double checked. btw, you may use a simple function to diagnose better. it could be like this: https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/examples/syncvalidation/

Answer (score 1):

I too get the same props.But I get the error object in sync errors.
[image]

[image]

Comment: That actually answers it. So to summarise, the sync errors will be found within the key `syncErrors`. Thank you.

Comment: Apologies for jumping the gun. It unfortunately doesn't solve the problem. The `sync error` is available on redux form, however, its not passed down to our component, surprisingly. Im going to continue looking into this...

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? So frustrating having the errors available but not being able to access them...